# What is the most efficient way to solve a workshop scheduling problem?

Tags: algorithm, optimization, combinatorics, minimization, max-flow

I am trying to design an algorithm to solve a workshop scheduling problem.

The problem is as follows:
I have to schedule a workshop consisting of a finite number of time slots, and a finite number of students. Each time slot has a capacity, which must be fulfilled. Each student has a list of preference corresponding to a set of time slots, where he/she wants to work.

For instance picture the following work shop:
[image]
where time slot 1,1 has capacity 3 and time slot 1,2 has capacity 4 and so on.

I want to optimize my scheduling so that students has the least overhead as possible. Overhead is defined as having to "wait" between work. For instance the following picture shows a student, that can work all three time slots in a day, but is only assigned to the first and the last, thus having one time slot overhead.
[image]
Thus: My objective function is to find a feasible solution while minimizing the students' total overhead.

My idea on how to solve it, is to construct a graph (see underneath), run a max-flow algorithm to determine a feasible solution, compute the total overhead (penalty), introduce some sort of randomization to change the schedule and compute the new overhead. Repeat the last 3 steps an arbitrary number of times to find the local minimum.

Graph:
[image]
Edit: Explanation of graph: The above graph shows 5 students, which each can be connected to up til 3 time slots. Each edge between a student and a time slot symbolizes that the student wants to work on that specific time slot. Each of these edges has a capacity of 1. The source node, S has edges to every student with the capacity of infinite, because each student can work as much as he/she wants. Each edge from a time slot to the sink node T, has a capacity, of the specific time slot's capacity.

Pseudo code

```
function solve-this(timeslots, students) {
    create graph from time slots and students
    run ford-folkerson max-flow algorithm to determine a feasible solution
    while(local optimal solution not found) {
        compute penalty / overhead
        if(computed penalty < current solution) {
            current solution = this solution
        }
        change schedule based on some sort of randomization factor
    }
    return solution
}
```

Is there any smarter way to do this? Is this the best way to find an somewhat optimal solution, without checking every possible schedule?

Any help, comments and/or feedback is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you search in the literature? This sounds like it could already be well researched.

Comment: To be honest, I haven't looked into much research, as I'm a bit confused on exactly what i should for.

Comment: You can search in litterature for problems called "Student Scheduling Problem" or "university course scheduling" for example, where your constraints are studied.

Comment: Thank you. I will try that.

Comment: If you remove the overhead, it's a generalized assignment problem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_assignment_problem), so you can search the litterature for related problems. If you can use existing solver, modifying the ILP for GAP should be quite easy to add the overhead penalties.

Comment: I agree that this fits the mold of Integer Linear Programming (ILP).  Trying to solve it as a network will be tough.  If you go the ILP route, you will need a solver.  If the problem is "small" you might be able to solve it in Excel, with its primitive solver.  Does each student have the same amount of work?  How do you intend to handle "student preferences"?  Satisfaction of preferences competes with waiting time in to objective??

Comment: How would I express this as an ILP-program, when my costs are dynamic? For instance if a student is matched to the first time slot on a given day, only a second match to the third time slot would incur a penalty / cost. If the student is matched to the first and the second time slot, no penalty should occur.
As i see it, a possible solution could be min-cost-max-flow where every time you pass a flow through certain edges, you modify all non-directly-adjacent edges to have a cost.

Comment: And regarding preferences, preferences might be the wrong word. The students simply select when they are available to work, but doesn't have a certain preference. And also as the problem is right now, there is no constraint on the amount of work, so lets assume that the problem should be solved with as few students as possible.